# Uncaught ReferenceError $ is not defined but jQuery has been loaded at sometime

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have JS code in web page like this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
        function table_data_update() {
            $jq.ajax({
                url: "query_issue.php",
                data: { "start_date": "20160705", "end_date": "20160706" },
                success: function (data) {
                    var table = document.getElementById("test_table");
                    $jq.each(data, function (k, v) {
                        table.innerHTML +=
                            "<tr><td>" + v.id + "</td><td>" + v.D1 + "</td><td>" + v.D2 + "</td><td>";
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr, options, error) {

                }
            });
        }
        function table_init() {
            setInterval(table_data_update, 30000);
        }
        $jq(document).ready(table_init); //<=Uncaught ReferenceError $jq is not defined
        alert($jq);
    </script>
```

At code `$jq(document).ready(table_init);`, it show error `uncaught referenceerror $ is not defined`.

I confirm jquery has been reference in html. I use Chrome DevTools to debug and set breakpoints at `var jq = jQuery.noConflict();` and `$jq(document).ready(table_init);`. The first breakpoint can execute successfully. BUT, the second breakpoint hit **twice**. First time is pass and popup tips shows jQuery has loaded. But second time is error and show `uncaught referenceerror $ is not defined`.

Can anyone help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: `$jq !== jq`, can't find pure `$` from your snippet.

Comment: `var jq = jQuery.noConflict`, so what does `$jq` equal?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I hate myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition should be `var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();` instead of `var jq = jQuery.noConflict();`. Try the code below:

```js
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
        function table_data_update() {
            $jq.ajax({
                url: "query_issue.php",
                data: { "start_date": "20160705", "end_date": "20160706" },
                success: function (data) {
                    var table = document.getElementById("test_table");
                    $jq.each(data, function (k, v) {
                        table.innerHTML +=
                            "<tr><td>" + v.id + "</td><td>" + v.D1 + "</td><td>" + v.D2 + "</td><td>";
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr, options, error) {

                }
            });
        }
        function table_init() {
            setInterval(table_data_update, 30000);
        }
        $jq(document).ready(table_init); //<=Uncaught ReferenceError $jq is not defined
        alert($jq);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. Feel so bad for my typo.

Comment: @KyL well apart from a typo, it's a misconception people could sometimes have when working with jQuery. Don't feel bad about it! ;)